# CloudFormation Elastic load balancer listener circular dependency with listener certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have a cloudformation template that is trying to create an application load balancer listener and it also attempts to create a listener certificate. The issue is both resources reference each other. I get a circular dependency error when validating the yaml configuration...

```
#APPLICATION LOAD BALANCER LISTENER
  ApplicationLoadBalancerListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties: 
      AlpnPolicy: 
        - String
      Certificates: 
        - !Ref ListenerCertificate
      DefaultActions: 
        - Action
      LoadBalancerArn: 
        Ref: ApplicationLoadBalancer
      Port: 443
      Protocol: HTTPS
      SslPolicy: ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08
  
#APPLICATION LOAD BALANCER LISTENER SSL LINK
  ListenerCertificate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerCertificate
    Properties: 
      Certificates: 
        - !Ref SSLCertificate
      ListenerArn:
        Ref: ApplicationLoadBalancerListener
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Certificates` shoud be ARN of certificate from ACM, `AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate`, not your `ListenerCertificate`.

Answer (score 3):

Marcin was correct. I needed to reference the Certificate (`AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate`), not `ListenerCertificate`.
Also correct syntax is:

```
  ApplicationLoadBalancerListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties: 
      Certificates: 
        - CertificateArn: !Ref SSLCertificate
```